# Fast way to get the length of serialized data using ProtoBuf-net?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Let's say I have a Person class. It has an editable Notes property.
I want to serialize the Person instance to a fixed size buffer, thus the Notes cannot be infinite long.
In the UI, I use a TextBox to let user edit the notes. I want to dynamically update a label saying how many more characters you can write.

This is my current implementation, is there any faster method? (I'm using rs282)

```
    public Int32 GetSerializedLength()
    {
        Byte[] data;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix<Person>(ms, this, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        { 
            Int32 length = 0;
            if (Serializer.TryReadLengthPrefix(ms, PrefixStyle.Base128, out length))
                return length;
            else
                return -1;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I'm confused about the internal lengh of the serialized data and the total length of the serialized data.
Here is my final version:

```
    private static MemoryStream _ms = new MemoryStream();
    public static Int64 GetSerializedLength(Person person)
    {
        if(null == person) return 0;
        _ms.SetLength(0);
        Serializer.Serialize<Person>(_ms, person);
        return _ms.Length;
    }
```

Comment: Normally you either handle the length yourself (Serialize and check .Length) or you let *it* worry about it (SerializeWithLengthPrefix) - can you clarify the scenario - I.e. Why do you need the internal (not external) length? Happy o help - just very curious...?

Comment: Oops, looks like I'm confused about the length. I might just need the external length.

Comment: @AZ so does Serialize (with or without WithLengthPrefix) and ms.Length / data.Length give what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the edit, it sounds like you want the length *without* serializing it (since if you want the length *with* serializing it, you'd just serialize it and check the `.Length`).

Basically, no - this isn't available. I know that some of the other implementations build this data eagerly, that is *in part* because they are constructing the buffered data all the time, where-as protobuf-net works from an object graph.

protobuf-net does *not* do this - it builds the data by discovery during a single pass over the object graph. Is there a specific purpose you have in mind? Things can always be added (with effort, though).

---

Re the issue of a notes (string) field that you don't want to be over-sized; as a sanity check, note that protubuf uses UTF8 or string data, so *personally* I would just do:

```
if(theText.Length > MAX || Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(theText) > MAX
       || GetSerializedLength(obj) > MAX)
{
        //
}
```

note we've checked this a bit more cheaply in the obvious cases

Comment: well as I said I'd like to display a text limit on the UI and prevent customer entering crazy long text, kind like PreviewSerializedDataLength(). Is that something you want to add in v2?